# GluonPresenter getApp() return null

Tags: gluon-mobile

I have a View's name is register.fxml that fx:controller="xxx.RegisterPresenter"
And load view by:(not use the AppViewManager to load)

```
URL url=presenterClass.getResource(id+".fxml");
view = (View)FXMLLoader.load(url);
```

that is working.
but when open the view and trigger the RegisterPresenter's initialize()，the getApp() can not return the MoblileApplication?(always null)
Please help me how to init the GluonPresenter correctly.

```
public class RegisterPresenter extends GluonPresenter<AppMain> {
public void initialize() {

    register.showingProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue) {
            AppBar appBar = **getApp().getAppBar();**//<==get return null?
            updateAppBar(appBar);
        }
    });
```

Comment: GlistenAfterburner abstracts away the manual loading of the fxml files and creation of views. You need to register your Presenter with the framework by making a call to `AppViewRegistry#createView`. This creates an `AppView` which can be added to the list of views by calling `AppView#register` and pass the `MobileApplication` instance to it. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/devoxx/MyDevoxxGluon/blob/master/DevoxxClientMobile/src/main/java/com/devoxx/DevoxxApplication.java#L98).

Answer (score 0):

Answer myself but not sure is correct.

IF want to get MobileApplication in view controller just call:

```
MobileApplication.getInstance();
```